# PHP passing data across pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, performance

I am trying to figure out the best way to pass data across two pages (Page A to Page B) using PHP for a (somewhat )specific scenario:

**Page A:** A gallery of images with titles.  To create this page, a database call is made in a PHP file to an images table that holds and image id, and image location, and an image title.  It gets all of the images that exist in the table and echoes them all out to the screen with a for loop.  It creates an href on each image's anchor tag that points to page B.

**Page B:** A larger view of the image.  When a user clicks on an image on Page A, it brings them to a new page with a larger view of the image.

To achieve this, I am currently putting an href on each anchor containing the images in Page A with a parameter containing the image id.  Then, on Page B, I make **another** database call using the id that was passed in to again get the image title, location, etc.

This seems wrong to me to make a second database call when I have already retrieved all of the needed data once on the previous page.  In my mind, there are only three decent options which all seem bad to me:

- **Multiple databse queries** - as explained above.  Seems inefficient.
- **GET** - Instead of just including the image id in the href on Page A, include ALL of the needed parameters in the href.  Note that I actually have more than just three parameters, and there may be upwards of 15 values that need to be passed.  It seems wrong to have a url this enormous and to be passing things like image location in the url.
- **POST** - Have a form on the page for each image with a method of `POST`.  Put a hidden field in the form for each parameter that needs to be passed form `Page A` to `Page B`.  Again this seems like a really bad idea to me to have tons of unnecessary markup and will get very messy.

Does anyone have any input on any of these methods, or a better idea?  As I develop more, I find myself questioning efficiency and how it doesn't make sense to me to make so many database calls that do the same thing over and over.  I want to be able to make one database call for one image once and then never have to do it again for that session.

(Note that `JavaScript / jQuery` is an option for me)

Thanks!

Comment: Would a SESSION array be appropriate? Then for Page B use AJAX?

Comment: The third option will be using session, but I think for you it will be too much information to manage in a session.
From your query it looks like you want to minimize your DB calls. In that case use memcache as an intermediate layer between your DB and PHP application. In your case you can store the array of images in memcache and retrieve it from memcache in the second page.

Comment: I had actually considered using sessions, but figured that it would be a ton of data to be storing (could be about a thousand images with 15 properties each). And then each user would have his own session.

Comment: @VineeshPoduval Thanks for the memchache idea, didn't know about this.  Would accept this as the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do what you are doing but using a function for it. The function would have

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $imageid
```

Passing the ID of the image you want and if there is no value in `$imageid` then show all. That way on page A you can use this to get the images and then just by using POST or GET with the ID you run the same function to get the results for the ID.

I would say that's not very messy to do it that way but again, that's just how I would do it.

Overall doing something like this:

```
function getImage ($imageid) {

  if($imageid == ""){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");
    return $result;

  } else {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $imageid");
    return $result;

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, guess I was on the right track.  Though I like Vineesh's memcache idea for reducing the number of database calls.

Answer (score 1):

It's the reality of web that you need to make a HTTP request every time to fetch some data from server. If you reloads a page browser will again make a HTTP request to get that data again. HTML5 have lot of solutions to the above problem...

1. Web Storage - Store Values as key-value pair on client side
2. Web SQL Database - Same as SQL
3. IndexedDB - Somewhere Between Web Storage and Web SQL Database

You need to create a base64 string out of your image & store that string in Web Storage or WebSQL database. You can write code for image to base64 in javascript file & then use HTML5 APIs to store the string in database.

Have a look at this page --  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, you won't have to go to the next page. you can simply do the below:

```
$('div#largeImageDisplay').hide(); // Div to display large image on. You can style however you want

$("a.linkClass").on("click", function(e) {
    sImagePath = $(this).children("img").attr("src"); // use replace function to change path to the one you want 
    sImageTitle = $(this).attr("title");

    $('div#largeImageDisplay').empty();
    $('div#largeImageDisplay').html("<h3>"+sImageTitle+"</h3><img src='"+sImagePath+"'/>");

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: No, use on() function. I'm using live on the latest jquery library and it works well.

Comment: The `live()` method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use the `on()` method instead.

Comment: The reason I didn't do it this way is because I want a page change / new URL.  Also, there is some more information that doesn't show up on the first page that is needed on the second.  To do this, I would have to hide this information on the page somewhere.